# JqueryUI: Mantener el estilo de la tabla al hacer un drag and drop

Tags: jquery, css, laravel

Tengo una tabla en la que muevo las filas utilizando la función draggable de JqueryUI.

El tamaño en ancho esta puesto con porcentajes para cada celda, pero al realizar el drag and drop estos porcentajes se ven alterados, además se puede 'sacar' la fila 'fuera' de la tabla.

Para que os hagáis una idea, la tabla se ve así si no se hace nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al mover la fila se puede ver así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la vista es el siguiente:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="tableemployees">       
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr class="tremployee">
            <th class="columnidemployee thcenter thmenuemp">ID</th>
            <th class="thcenter thmenuemp columnvisibleemp" >Visible</th>
            <th class="thmenuemp thmenuempname">Nombre</th>
            <th class="thmenuemp">#Hashtag</th>
            <th class="thmenuemp">Slug</th>
            <th class="thmenuemp">Puesto</th>
            <th class="thmenuemp thmenuimagen">Imagen</th>
            <th class="thcenter thmenuemp thmenuorden">Orden</th>
            <th class="thaccionesemployee thmenuemp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbodyemployee">
          @foreach ($employees as $key => $employee)
            <tr id="{{$employee->id}}">
              <td class="idemployees tdcenter"><p id="margindataemployee">{{$employee->id}}</p></td>
              <td class="visibleemployee tdcenter"> 
              <form action="{{route('admin.employees.cambiarVisible',$employee->id)}}" >
              <button type="button" id="buttonchangepublicemployee" data-id="{{ $employee->id }}" class="buttonchangepublicemployee">
                  @if ($employee->public == '1')
                            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" id="margindataemployee" class="cambiarsiporno"></i>
                   @else
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindataemployee"></i>
                   @endif
              </button>
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
              </form>
              </td>
              <td class="nameemployee"><p id="margindataemployee">{{$employee->name}}</p></td>
              <td class="nameemployee2"><p id="margindataemployee">{{$employee->name}}</p><img src="{{ asset('/storage/employees/'.$employee->slug.'.jpg')}}" class="sizeimage"></td>
              <td class="hashtagemp"><p id="margindataemployee">#{{$employee->hashtag}}</p></td>
              <td class="hashtagemp2"><p id="margindataemployee" class="hashtagempp">#{{$employee->hashtag}}</p>  
              @if ($employee->public == '1')
                       <p class="pvisible">Visible:</p><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>
              @else
                       <p class="pvisible">Visible:</p><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>
              @endif
              </td>
              <td class="slugemployee"><p id="margindataemployee" class="slugemp">{{$employee->slug}}</p></td>
              <td class="slugemployee2"><p id="margindataemployee">{{$employee->slug}}</p>
               <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.employees.destroy',$employee->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrarTrabajadores()" class="formeditdeletemenuemployee4">
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-danger-emp btn-sm" id="margindataemployee">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
                            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                          </form>
              </td>
              <td class="puestoemployee"><p id="margindataemployee">{{$employee->position}}</p></td>
              <td class="imagenemployee"><img src="{{ asset('/storage/employees/'.$employee->slug.'.jpg')}}" class="sizeimage"></td>
              <td class="ordenemployee tdcenter"><p id="margindataemployee">{{$employee->order}}</p>
              <div class="formeditdeletemenuemployee">
                <a href="{{ route('admin.employees.edit', $employee->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-success-emp btn-sm" id="margindataemployee">Editar</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deletemenuemployee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formdeleteemployee_{{$employee->id}}" id="margindata">Borrar</button>
               </div>
              </td>
              <td class="formactionmenuemployee"> 
                <a href="{{ route('admin.employees.edit', $employee->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-success-emp btn-sm" id="margindataemployee">Editar</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deletemenuemployee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formdeleteemployee_{{$employee->id}}" id="margindata">Borrar</button>
            </td>

              <div id="formdeleteemployee_{{$employee->id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->
                          <div class="modal-dialog" style="background-color:#23517F;">
                          <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#23517F;">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;">¿Estas seguro de borrar el trabajador?</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <a href="{{ route('admin.employees') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block colsm6btnno">No</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.employees.destroy',$employee->id)}}">
                                  <input type="submit" value="Si" class="btn btn-danger btn-block colsm6btnsi inputsiemployee">
                                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
                                  {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                              </form>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closemodal">Close</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
         </tr>
         @endforeach
       </tbody>
     </table>
     <br><br>
   </div>
</div>
```

Se que como norma general, no se debe poner un elemento `<div>` dentro de un elemento `<td>`, pero ese no es el causante del problema de los estilos.

No se si puede ayudar, el `<tr>` tiene style `display:table-row` pero cuando hago el drag, pasa a tener `display:none;`

¿Se os ocurre que puedo hacer con los estilos, para solucionar el problema?

https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/8/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el jsfiddle que adjuntas no se ve nada raro.. :/

Comment: Prueba a arrastrar una fila hacia la derecha, ahora te adjunto una imagen igualmete.

Comment: He hecho todo tipo de movimientos con la fila y no me pasa eso. Si que queda a veces *pillado* durante medio segundo pero se acaba colocando en su sitio

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68643/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-lois6b).